# Chrome and Slack crashing Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: 20.04, google-chrome, slack

I have got strange problem that I can't resolve long time. During work I use Slack, Chrome and Intellij IDEA.
In some moment when I move mouse in Chrome - that areas of screen change on white rectangles and then interrupt Slack and after Chrome interrupts too.
But then I cannot execute Chrome and Slack again and have to restart PC.
That happens several times per day.

What is happening with my Chrome and Slack? How could I fix it?
Nowhere found the same problem.

results of commands:

1. `uname -r`: `5.10.0-1029-oem`
2. `sudo lshw -C video`:

```
*-display                 
       description: VGA compatible controller
       product: UHD Graphics
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 2
       bus info: pci@0000:00:02.0
       version: 02
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pciexpress msi pm vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
       configuration: driver=i915 latency=0
       resources: irq:156 memory:df000000-dfffffff memory:a0000000-afffffff ioport:3000(size=64) memory:c0000-dffff
```

Comment: What do you mean by "crashing"? Edit your question and show me `uname -r` and `sudo lshw -C video`. Which video card? What version driver?

Comment: I edited question with results of commands. Video card is integrated Intel. How can I check version driver? @heynnema
Some characteristics: 32 RAM, Intel i7, HP laptop ZBook

Comment: Go to https://www.memtest86.com/ and download/run their free `memtest` to test your memory. Get at least one complete pass of all the 4/4 tests to confirm good memory. This may take many hours to complete.

Comment: I've started to experience exactly the same problem about 2 weeks ago. In my case I'm also using Skype and it also stops working until I restart my computer. It seems like both Chrome and Skype are using the same JS rendering engine library or resource under the hood, which gets overloaded and doesn't get up until restart.

Interestingly though - Firefox works well

Comment: FYI, `uname -r` outputs `5.11.0-27-generic` and `sudo lshw -C video` outputs almost the same output as in OP. So this might be the problem with the driver for this graphics card